# Parse server: How to get exact amount of registered users

Tags: parse-server

I have several millions of users in by database. Is there a way how i can get the exact amount of users registered? 
I want to implement a live user registration counter.

The default way is to use the count query from the sdk, but it has limitation to 1000 rows. I need a solution for millions of rows, without any additional indexing or modifications to the DB. Is there such?

Answer (score 3):

The 1000 query limit is for the old parse.com server.
On parse-server, this limit has been removed and you can count above 1000.

https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#counting-objects

You should note that this is an expensive query and you should consider creating an object that stores the total number of users and increases when a new user is created.
You can do this with beforeSave triggers
e.g

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, async(req) => {
if (!req.object.existed()){
    const userCount = await new Parse.Query('Statistics').equalTo('name', 'user_count').first({useMasterKey: true});
    userCount.increment('count');
    userCount.save(null, {useMasterKey: true});
}});
```